# Connecting menu items to the first responder and multiple view controllers at the same time

Tags: swift, xcode, first-responder, nsviewcontroller

I have a main view controller with a container view in it. I’m able to create an IBAction in the main view controller and connect a  menu item to that action in the first responder successfully. But when connecting a different menu item to the container view controllers action, the menu item stays grayed out.

[image]

In the main view controller:

```
@IBAction func outerMenuTest(_ sender: Any) {
    print("outerMenuTest")
}
```

In the container view controller:

```
@IBAction func containerMenuTest(_ sender: Any) {
    print("containerMenuTest")
}
```

How do you connect menu items to view controllers in container view controllers at the same time? I need both menu items enabled.

Comment: By the looks of your `IBAction`s it seems you want one menu item to trigger two different methods with the same name to fire. This is unlikely to work out very well… Consider connecting one of the methods and firing a notification that other controllers can subscribe to and react accordingly to. If you only want one of the `IBAction`s to fire connect the menu to the first responder in the storyboard. When the menu is fired the system will work its way through the responder chain and find the _first_ instance that responds to the specified selector.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to change the function names while writing the question. The real code has different names.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to connect menu items to anything other than the app delegate is to use the First Responder in storyboard. You will need to have already created the `IBAction` is the appropriate class before making the connection. You may also need to clean and/or build the project to force Xcode to index all the `IBAction`s.

Provided Xcode is behaving and the actions are in classes Xcode sees as a potential first responder it will show up in the list of options when you control drag from the menu item to `First Responder` in the outline on the left of the canvas:

[image]

`First Responder` is a proxy for the whole responder chain. When something points to it the system will start with the first responder and work its way up the responder chain until it finds one that responds to the specified selector. As long as your container view is in the responder chain it will get the message.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done, but it does not work. How do you connect a container view to the responder chain?